# Capture repetitive pattern only if the string/line starts or contains with a specific char before the group

Tags: regex

Hello I am trying to capture a repetitive pattern `x.x.x.x` where x is a number (one digit or more) but to capture only if the whole line or string starts or contains a "@" before the group:

> This is a test @ 1.2.3.4 which 11.2.38.49 should pass 3.2.4.5 and capture the 3 groups
>
> This @ is a test 1.2.3.4 which 1.2.3.4 should pass 3.2.4.5 too
>
> @This is a test  1.2.3.4 which 1.2.3.4 should pass 3.2.4.5 too
>
> This is a test  1.2.3.4 which @ 1.2.3.4 pass 3.2.4.5 but don't capture the first group
>
> This test  1.2.3.4  1.2.3.4 should @ pass but capture nothing
>
> This test  1.2.3.4  1.2.3.4 should test fail

so far I have `(\d*\.\d+)+` is it even possible to find a regex for it?

https://regex101.com/r/G81BBj/1

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: Why `This test  1.2.3.4  1.2.3.4 should @ pass but capture nothing` ? Else You could use a quantifier in the lookbehind if supported `(?<=@.*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)` https://regex101.com/r/elu0xA/1

Comment: i agree we can suppose if fails, i don't know about quantifiers in lookbehinde, the link you provide show patter error

Comment: The link works https://regex101.com/r/elu0xA/1 but on the left side ECMAScript is selected because this part `(?<=@.*)` does not work in all engines.

Comment: I have tried with all the engines available on regex101 including ECMAScript. (?<=@.*) '?' is red and is showing "the preceding token is not quantifiable"

Comment: I see, can you open it in Chrome instead? That engine supports it.

Comment: I don't have it right now, later i will see

Comment: The .NET engine also supports it, see a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%40.*%29%28%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%2b%29&i=This+is+a+test+%40+1.2.3.4+which+11.2.38.49+should+pass+3.2.4.5+%0d%0aThis+%40+is+a+test+1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+should+pass+3.2.4.5+too%0d%0a%40This+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+should+pass+3.2.4.5+too%0d%0aThis+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+%40+1.2.3.4+pass+3.2.4.5+but+not+capture+first+group%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+should+%40+pass+but+apture+nothing%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+should+test+fail)

Comment: nice in order to achieve my requirement I should use quantifiers in lookbehinde and regex engin should support ECMAScript right ?

Comment: Not necessarily ECMAScript, there are a few engines that support finite/infinite width in a lookbehind. See https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width Or if the engine supports `\G` https://regex101.com/r/dVVhNn/1

Comment: Is not the best solution to code a regex to match a "candidate string" and then extract the  "numbers" from the match in a programmed loop, such as with Python or Perl?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes thanks this is the result I am looking for. Can you make it as an answer with little details/explanation? especially why in your link here https://regex101.com/r/dVVhNn/1 same regex, same options "/gm" and without pattern error for all engines (except Golang) gives different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different [regex engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines) where some support different features than others.

If you want to match all occurrences of a dot-separated chunk, you could make use of a [quantifier in a lookbehind assertion](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width).

Match 1+digits, and repeat matching a dot and 1+ digits at least
one or more times to prevent matching only digits.

```
(?<=@.*)\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

- `(?<=@.*)` Positive lookbehind, assert that there is an @ on the left
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\.\d+` Match a dot and 1+ digits
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to make sure there is at least 1 dot present

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%40.*%29%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%2b&i=This+is+a+test+%40+1.2.3.4+which+11.2.38.49+should+pass+3.2.4.5+%0d%0aThis+%40+is+a+test+1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+should+pass+3.2.4.5+too%0d%0a%40This+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+should+pass+3.2.4.5+too%0d%0aThis+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+%40+1.2.3.4+pass+3.2.4.5+but+not+capture+first+group%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+should+%40+pass+but+apture+nothing%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+should+test+fail)

---

Another option could be when the engine supports the `\G` anchor which will assert either at the start of the string, or asserts the position at the end of the previous match.

```
(?:^[^\r\n@]*@|\G(?!^)).*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)
```

- `(?:` Non capture group
- `^[^\r\n@]*@` Match from the start of the string until the first @

  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `.*?` Match as least char as possible
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` Match a dot-separated chunk
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dVVhNn/1)

If the engine does not support `\G` and the engine will recognize `\G` as a G char, it will first try to match until the first occurrence of an @ followed by matching until the dot-separated chunk.

After matching the first dot-separated chunk, it tries for all the following positions to match the first part of the alternation, which can not match due to the `^` anchor. It tries the second part, but that will not match because there is no `G` char in the example data so eventually there will be only a single match.

---

If `\K` to is also supported to clear the starting point of the reported match, for example in pcre, you could omit the capturing group and get the match only:

```
(?:^[^\r\n@]*@|\G(?!^)).*?\K\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iYYTa3/1)

Answer (score 0):

With any regex engine that supports unknown width patterns in lookbehind (.NET, ECMAScript 2018+, PyPi regex module in Python, JGSoft Software), you may use

```
(?<=@.*?)\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%40.*%3f%29%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29*&i=This+is+a+test+%40+1.2.3.4+which+11.2.38.49%0d%0aThis+%40+is+a+test+1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+%0d%0a%40This+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+%0d%0aThis+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+%40+1.2.3.4+%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+).

**Details**

- `(?<=@.*?)` - a location that is immediately preceded with `@` char that may be followed with any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` - one or more digits followed with 0 or more occurrences of a dot and then 1+ digits.

Comment: Thanks, but no in fact i want to capture all occurrences of "dot-separated digit chunk" as long as there is an "@" before the pattern.

Comment: @ashley Then use `(?<=@.*?)\d+(?:\.\d+)*`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%40.*%3f%29%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29*&i=This+is+a+test+%40+1.2.3.4+which+11.2.38.49%0d%0aThis+%40+is+a+test+1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+%0d%0a%40This+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+1.2.3.4+%0d%0aThis+is+a+test++1.2.3.4+which+%40+1.2.3.4+%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+%0d%0aThis+test++1.2.3.4++1.2.3.4+)